# Completely baffled by this question involving putting matrices in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices

This is homework, so only hints please.

> Let $A\in M_{m\times m}(\mathbb{R})$
>    , $B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$
>    . Suppose there exist orthogonal matrices $P$
>     and $Q$
>     such that $P^{T}AP$
>     and $Q^{T}BQ$
>     are upper triangular. Let $C$
>     be any $m\times n$ matrix. Then show that there is an orthogonal $R$
>    , not depending on $C$
>    , such that $$R^{T} \begin{bmatrix}A & C\\
> 0 & B
> \end{bmatrix}R$$
>    is upper triangular.

I haven't done any proofs before using matrices containing matrices in them. I have *absolutely* no idea where to begin. Any ideas?

Comment: In general, these guys are called block matrices and can, more or less, be multiplied out as through they were numerical entries. There have to be some constraints on the size of the matrix. For example, if $C$ is an $m$-by-$m$ matrix and $R$ is and $n$-by-$n$ matrix, then you need $n \ge m$.

Comment: C is $m\times n$.

Comment: Hint (I haven't tried it but I suspect it will work): Play with $R$, write it in some sort of block matrix form and try to fill in the blocks for your objective. For example, you are given that $P^T A P$ is upper triangular. You may try to put $P$ somewhere in $R$, when multiplied you will aim to get $P^TAP$ which is upper triangular. Once you do that with $B$ too, you will hopefully make the bigger matrix upper triangular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take

$$R = \operatorname{diag}(P,Q) = \begin{bmatrix} P \\ & Q \end{bmatrix},$$

and see what happens. Ask if you get stuck.

Comment: Ahh thanks. I was trying to concoct $R$ using multiplications and sums of things involving $P$ and $Q$...

Also, is there some trick to intuitively "getting" matrix multiplication? Like, I can calculate it, but I can never eyeball even a very high-level picture of what happens to various properties when you multiply two matrices.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's basically a vector-vector multiplication (inner, or scalar, product) of each row of the left matrix with each column of the right matrix. Block-matrices can be treated just as regular ones, as long as all the block sizes fit (so that their products exist).

Answer (score 0):

The elements of a matrix must be add-able and multiply-able (and the addition and multiplication have to satisfy some field properties).

Matrices themselves are add-able and multiply-able (except that AB isn't necessarily BA), so they can be elements of another matrix.

$\begin {bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} \begin {bmatrix} E & F \\ G & H \end{bmatrix}  = \begin {bmatrix} A E + B G & A F + B H \\ C E + D F & C G + D H \end{bmatrix}$

In your problem, we want to find

$\begin {bmatrix} X & Y \\ 0 & Z \end{bmatrix} = \begin {bmatrix} R_A & R_B \\ R_C & R_D\end{bmatrix}^T \begin {bmatrix} A & C \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix} \begin {bmatrix} R_A &  R_B \\ R_C & R_D \end{bmatrix}$

where $X$ and $Z$ are upper triangular.

$ = \begin {bmatrix} R_A^T & R_C^T \\ R_B^T & R_D^T\end{bmatrix} \begin {bmatrix} A & C \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix} \begin {bmatrix} R_A &  R_B \\ R_C & R_D \end{bmatrix}$

$ = \begin {bmatrix} R_A^T A & R_A^TC + R_C^T B \\ R_B^TA & R_B^TC + R_D^T B\end{bmatrix} \begin {bmatrix} R_A &  R_B \\ R_C & R_D \end{bmatrix}$

$ = \begin {bmatrix} R_A^T A R_A + R_A^TCR_C + R_C^T B R_C & R_A^T A R_B + R_A^TCR_D + R_C^T B R_D \\ R_B^T A R_A + R_B^TCR_C + R_D^T B R_C & R_B^T A R_B + R_B^TCR_D + R_D^T B R_D\end{bmatrix}$

So we want to chose R so that:

$\begin{align}
\text{Upper Triangular} &= R_A^T A R_A + R_A^TCR_C + R_C^T B R_C \\
\text{Anything} &= R_A^T A R_B + R_A^TCR_D + R_C^T B R_D \\
\text{Zero} &= R_B^T A R_A + R_B^TCR_C + R_D^T B R_C \\
\text{Upper Triangular} &= R_B^T A R_B + R_B^TCR_D + R_D^T B R_D \\
\\
\text{Given that:} \\
\text{Upper Triangular} &= P^TAP \\
\text{Upper Triangular} &= Q^TBQ \\
\end{align}$

You can see by looking at the equations now that you want some terms to be upper triangular and some to be zero.  Fit in $R_A = P$, $R_B = 0$, $R_C = 0$, and $R_D = Q$, you get:

$\begin{align}
\text{Upper Triangular} &= P^T A P + P^TC0 + 0^T B 0 \\
                        &= P^T A P \\
\text{Anything} &= P^T A 0 + P^TCQ + 0^T B Q \\
                &= P^TCQ \\
\text{Zero} &= 0^T A P + 0^TC0 + Q^T B 0 \\
            &= 0 \\
\text{Upper Triangular} &= 0^T A 0 + 0^TCQ + Q^T B Q \\
                        &= Q^T B Q \\
\end{align}$

$R = \begin {bmatrix} P & 0 \\ 0 & Q \end{bmatrix}$